# 500 errors for some GET products calls

Tags: bigcommerce

We have a client with 1344 products.

Calling the GET on orders over multiple pages (250 per page), yields results for all pages except page 3. The response is a 500 error.

Using a limit of 200 per page yields results for all pages except page 4.

UPDATE:
Here are details about the API call, status and response body.
HTTP GET https://www.STORE-NAME.com:443/api/v2/products.json?limit=250&page=3
Response status   Net::HTTPInternalServerError (500)
Response body   ?

The actual call is done via the official Bigcommerce API gem, which uses RestClient under the hood.

Is this a known bug - any ideas?

Comment: have you looked in your server's error log to see what the error message listed in it is?

Comment: Example of code? Error message when debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has since been reportedly fixed by BigCommerce.